# Should I edit a bad question?

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits, editing-help, bad-questions

Is it worth editing a question for readability and formatting if the content is very poor or it meets one or more flagging reasons?

I'm guessing no, since it's highly likely to be deleted anyway, but I'd like some community input.